# Except put database data in array, what the alternative way to passing data before the amount?

Tags: php, arrays, email

I am currently developing a project which according to blast email. Now I am using cronjob to blast email every certain duration. In my sql, I select 600 email to send as a time but my server only support 200 email at 1 hour. Therefore, I create 3 different SMTP email to blast email faster which every email have blast 200 email at every 1 hours. What I need to do next is count inside loop which first 200 email selected from database pass to first SMTP email and the following 400 pass to another 2 SMTP email. But I found my code having some problem because what I am doing is run all database email inside a loop one by one. Which mean `$count` I assign into loop will be only run 1 time every loop. This will cause my email cannot send via 3 different email at 1 time. So, is that necessary for me to using array to store different database email for every 200 before send out? What I mean is define 3 different array inside another loop and then run 3 different array independently. Like following :

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($database); $i++){
    if($i < 200){
    $array1[] = $row['email'];
    }
    else if($i < 400){
    array2[] = $row['email'];
    }
    else{
    array3[] = $row['email'];
    }
    }
```

This is what I think while use array and I will use for loop after store all database email into array above. But is there have alternative ways to send email concurrently via 3 different email?

Below is what I am done and this way will not be what I want because of the loop:

```
<?
require_once "lib/base.inc.php";

$arrResult = $oAdminEmail->getQueEmail();
$count = 0 ;
for($i=0; $i<count($arrResult); $i++)
{
$count++;
if($count < 200){
    $smptusername = "email1";
    $smptpassword = "password";
    $smptport = "587";
    $email = $arrResult[$i]['contact_email'];
    $name = null;
    $message = $arrResult[$i]['message']; 
    $subject = $arrResult[$i]['subject'];
    $sendMail = $eMailer->sendEDM($email,$name,$subject,$message,$smptusername,$smptpassword,$smptport);
    $iId = $arrResult[$i]['id'];
    if ($sendMail) 
            {
                $update['status'] = 1;
                $update_edm = $oAdminEmail->updateEmailStatus($update,$iId);
            }
            }
elseif($count < 400 ){
$smptusername = " email2";
$smptpassword = "password";
$smptport = "465";
    $email = $arrResult[$i]['contact_email'];
    $name = null;
    $message = $arrResult[$i]['message']; 
    $subject = $arrResult[$i]['subject'];
    $sendMail = $eMailer->sendEDM($email,$name,$subject,$message,$smptusername,$smptpassword,$smptport);
    $iId = $arrResult[$i]['id'];
    if ($sendMail) 
            {
                $update['status'] = 1;
                $update_edm = $oAdminEmail->updateEmailStatus($update,$iId);
            }

            }
else{
$smptusername = "email3";
$smptpassword = "password";
$smptport = "465";
    $email = $arrResult[$i]['contact_email'];
    $name = null;
    $message = $arrResult[$i]['message']; 
    $subject = $arrResult[$i]['subject'];
    $sendMail = $eMailer->sendEDM($email,$name,$subject,$message,$smptusername,$smptpassword,$smptport);
    $iId = $arrResult[$i]['id'];
    if ($sendMail) 
            {
                $update['status'] = 1;
                $update_edm = $oAdminEmail->updateEmailStatus($update,$iId);
            }
            } 
            }



?>
```

Appreciate for your help.

Comment: Don't come here asking for help on how to spam users.

Comment: FYI don't leave your ACTUAL login and passwords in your script. That's just asking for trouble

Comment: I am not spam user dude. I am looking for help. I now currently develop a system and I will send out 10k of email from my database. Please do not simply judge people if you are not trying to help. I have developed this email blaster but I just want to send it more faster. This is my main purpose.

Comment: I am not really understand your ideas. Can you provide me a sample code?

Comment: Why is there a 200 per hour limit? Is it a physical limit i.e. the server cannot process them fast enough? Or is there a limit imposed by the service provider? If there is a physical limit then the code is trivial.  You are almost there.

Comment: means what I do is correct? or other means?

Comment: Was wrong about it being trivial. you need to run three separate 'server' scripts that are sending the emails, as separate processes! They get the email message to send from a 'global' queue of the email messages. The issue is that the 'send email' blocks the current script from running until it finishes. The biggest issue is the 'server' script talking to the 'global' queue. I suggest using either a database or a shared file to pass status information around. I would use an 'sqlite' database for this job. It would be ideally suited.

Comment: If no one answers the question i may have a go at this. It looks interesting and fun.

Comment: I hope that you can provide me a sample answer. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Looks as though i have a project over the weekend :-)

Comment: do you get any result for me?

Comment: i will have something useful later today :-)

Comment: do you have any result yet?

Comment: sorry for the delay, the dog ate my homework. ;-/ i am writing the 'server locking code' as i speak. will get back to you later.

Comment: is ok. i am glad to waiting you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save your email accounts in an array

```
$ArrEmailAccount = array(
                        array('Username'=>'email1','Password'=>'password','Port'=>587),
                        array('Username'=>'email2','Password'=>'password','Port'=>465),
                        array('Username'=>'email3','Password'=>'password','Port'=>465)
                    );
```

Then do the for loop, changing accounts everytime you reach 200 emails.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($arrResult); $i++) {
    if ($i % 200 == 0) {
        $EmailCount = $i/200;
    }
    . . .
    $sendMail = $eMailer->sendEDM($email,$name,$subject,$message,$ArrEmailAccount[$EmailCount]['Username'],$ArrEmailAccount[$EmailCount]['Password'],$ArrEmailAccount[$EmailCount]['Port']);
    . . .
}
```

Add as many accounts as you want to accommodate more email addresses.

Comment: but what I trying to do is send 600 email via 3 different SMTP email concurrently. What you have try is same with me. it will run until 200 only will send via different email. For my case, my server only can support 200 email sent out via 1 SMTP email within 1 hour. Therefore, at the end at your code only can sent out 200 email within one hour. If there is 600 email, it will take around 3 hours to finish all 600 email. Do you get my mean? appreciate on your help. Thanks.